# Переключение класса active

Tags: jquery

[image: переключение соайдов]

```js
   

$('.slider-nav--next').on('click', function(){
        $('.slider-nav--prev').removeClass('slider--active');
        $(this).addClass('slider--active');

});
$('.slider-nav--prev').on('click', function(){
   $('.slider-nav--next').removeClass('slider--active');
   $(this).addClass('slider--active');
});
```

```css
.slider-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 74px;
  border: 1px solid #c19a64;
}

.slider--active {
  background-color: #c19a64;
 }
 
 .slider-navs {
  padding: 10px 12px 7px 10px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-button">
    <div class="slider-navs slider-nav--prev slider--active">←</div>
    <div class="slider-navs slider-nav--next">→</div>
</div>
```

Этот блок со стрелками находится на слайдере, проблема в том что при клике на стрелку прокрутки больше одного раза переключается на другую, а так не нужно ибо слайдов может быть не один, помогите плизз....  ]

Comment: Вопрос снимается, сделал но костыльно, у кого есть мысли как это все уменьшить welcom ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подобные штуки пишу так)

```js
$('.slider-button .slider-navs').on('click', function(){
  $('.slider-button .slider-navs').removeClass('slider--active');
  $(this).addClass('slider--active');
});
```

```css
.slider-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 74px;
  border: 1px solid #c19a64;
}

.slider--active {
  background-color: #c19a64;
 }
 
 .slider-navs {
  padding: 10px 12px 7px 10px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider-button">
    <div class="slider-navs slider-nav--prev slider--active">←</div>
    <div class="slider-navs slider-nav--next">→</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Окей !) Спасибо !

Answer (score 0):

с внедрением id

```
    <script>
$('#next').click(function () {
    $('#prev').removeClass('slider--active');
    $(this).addClass('slider--active');
});
$('#prev').click(function () {
    $('#next').removeClass('slider--active');
    $(this).addClass('slider--active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

или вот так...

```
    <script>
$('.slider-navs').click(function () {
    if($('.slider-navs').hasClass('slider--active')) {
      $('.slider-navs').removeClass('slider--active')
    }
    $(this).addClass('slider--active')
});
```